# Print preview is not working same in both firefox and chrome

Tags: css, printing

I have a horizontally lengthy page with table format, when I am trying to do a print preview in chrome half of the page are cutoff, but firefox rendering fine what I want looking for(auto shrink and fit to page). Any css solution is appreciated.

Comment: Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/jaisonjjames/17eq1b90/

Comment: did you try the custom stylesheet?

Comment: yes, but after my research I think there is no option like shrink to fit with chrome

Answer (score 0):

You could try creating a custom print stylesheet for your site and setting the width of the body to `100%` like this:

```
body {
    width: 100%;
}
```

See [this site](http://www.sitepoint.com/create-a-customized-print-stylesheet-in-minutes/) which has info on making a custom print CSS file.